# I can only see the error in the code when I inspect the element on the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the code of the website I have a mouseover and a imagemapresizer code to make maps interactive, but it doesn't work properly because of some 
 that I can only see when I inspect the element on the browser and I don't know how to fix that properly
[That's the page](https://www.arcanjohotel.com/localizacao/)
That's the code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="gdlr-content">

        <!-- Above Sidebar Section-->
        <?php global $gdlr_post_option, $above_sidebar_content, $with_sidebar_content, $below_sidebar_content; ?>
        <?php if(!empty($above_sidebar_content)){ ?>
            <div class="above-sidebar-wrapper"><?php gdlr_print_page_builder($above_sidebar_content); ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
        
        <!-- Sidebar With Content Section-->
        <?php 
            if( !empty($gdlr_post_option['sidebar']) && ($gdlr_post_option['sidebar'] != 'no-sidebar' )){
                global $gdlr_sidebar;
                
                $gdlr_sidebar = array(
                    'type'=>$gdlr_post_option['sidebar'],
                    'left-sidebar'=>$gdlr_post_option['left-sidebar'], 
                    'right-sidebar'=>$gdlr_post_option['right-sidebar']
                ); 
                $gdlr_sidebar = gdlr_get_sidebar_class($gdlr_sidebar);
        ?>
            <div class="with-sidebar-wrapper">
                <div class="with-sidebar-container container">
                    <div class="with-sidebar-left <?php echo esc_attr($gdlr_sidebar['outer']); ?> columns">
                        <div class="with-sidebar-content <?php echo esc_attr($gdlr_sidebar['center']); ?> columns">
                            <?php 
                                if( !empty($with_sidebar_content) ){
                                    gdlr_print_page_builder($with_sidebar_content, false);
                                }
                                if( !empty($gdlr_post_option['show-content']) && $gdlr_post_option['show-content'] != 'disable' ){
                                    get_template_part('single/content', 'page');
                                }
                            ?>                          
                        </div>
                        <?php get_sidebar('left'); ?>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <?php get_sidebar('right'); ?>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>              
            </div>              
        <?php 
            }else{ 
                if( !empty($with_sidebar_content) ){ 
                    echo '<div class="with-sidebar-wrapper">';
                    gdlr_print_page_builder($with_sidebar_content);
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                if( empty($gdlr_post_option['show-content']) || $gdlr_post_option['show-content'] != 'disable' ){
                    get_template_part('single/content', 'page');
                }
            } 
        ?>
        
        <!-- Below Sidebar Section-->
        <?php if(!empty($below_sidebar_content)){ ?>
            <div class="below-sidebar-wrapper"><?php gdlr_print_page_builder($below_sidebar_content); ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
                    
    </div><!-- gdlr-content -->
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Início do código para o hover no mapa - colocar no final do arquivo html -->


<map name="legenda" id="legenda">
    <area alt="bh" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="744,728,977,748" />
    <area alt="mariana" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="745,767,922,785" />
    <area alt="ob" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="745,803,959,820" />
    <area alt="transfer" title="" href="#" shape="rect" coords="745,839,1087,860" />
</map>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      imageMapResize();
    $('#legenda area').each(function () {
    // Assigning an action to the mouseover event
    $(this).mouseover(function (e) {
      var id = "#" + $(this).attr('alt');
      $(id).show();
      $("#base").hide();
    });

    // Assigning an action to the mouseout event
    $(this).mouseout(function (e) {
      var id = "#" + $(this).attr('alt');
      $(id).hide();
      $("#base").show();
    });

  });
</script>

    
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I honestly haven't tried anything yet because I really don't know how to do it, I'm not good with html/css, anything with websites in general and I expect it to work somehow

Answer (score 0):

In gdlr-script.js it's using jQuery.load. This was removed in jQuery version 3.
According to the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/load-shorthand/), you should replace:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
```

with:

```js
$(window).on('load', function(){
```

Comment: where do I replace it? I can't find the original one

Comment: As I said above it's in gdlr-script.js. In the page you linked it's one of the script tags imported at the bottom of the page: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.arcanjohotel.com/wp-content/themes/hotelmaster/javascript/gdlr-script.js?ver=1.0" id="gdlr-script-js"></script>`

Comment: I don't actually know if this is affecting the issue you mentioned, but I can see that it's a problem with the page and you said that there was a problem with inspection and this is all I can see in the console that's a problem.